# C# adding context menu item to windows explorer for all file types

Tags: c#, registry, windows-explorer

I'm currently writing an application where I need to modify the context menu of windows explorer so that I can call a method within the application to be used on all files/folders that are seen in windows explorer.

As there are already quite a few posts on stackoverflow (and also tutorials) on how to add the context menu for specific file types I know already that that is done usually by assigning the application to the right parts of the registry entry for those file types.

As I don't want to limit myself to only specific filetypes my question is: IS there any way
to assign this new context menu item to ALL filetypes (aside from going through each registry entry
beginning with . and assigning the application to them there)?

Comment: do you know that writing shell extension in C# is highly unsuggested? More info [HERE](http://sharpshell.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Managed%20Shell%20Extensions&referringTitle=Documentation)
Also, do you have used some kind a library to do this? With [SHARPSHELL](http://sharpshell.codeplex.com/) is pretty easy to achieve your goal

Comment: Yepp, I know that writing shell extensions is unsuggested. problem is that part of the restrictions for the project I'm working on is that it is to be written in C# and only there. Thus if something is not possible I can argue with the customer there, but if it is "just" not recommended I have a weak stand to argue.  didnt know about sharpshell so far reading it through tnx

Comment: A basic registry based association is not a shell extension and is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the `*` class:

1. Create the key:

   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with MyThing`
2. Create the sub key:

   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with MyThing\command`
3. Set the *default* value to your command line:

   `C:\foo\myThing.exe "%1"`

   (You can add fixed values here also: `C:\foo\myThing.exe "%1" /ranfromshell`)
4. To set an optional icon create the string *value* `Icon` in:

   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with MyThing`

   You can put the path to an icon, dll or exe here - Windows will extract the appropriate icon & display it.

---

### Example

[image: cap1]

For:

[image: cap2]

---

### .Reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with MyThing]
"Icon"="C:\\foo\\myThing.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with MyThing\command]
@="C:\\foo\\myThing.exe \"%1\""
```

Comment: hmmm I'm doing something wrong there?. I'm using HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My context Menu Name\command and set the default value to the commandline value, but it doesnt show anything 
(tried it with command and Command).

Comment: Works for me, added a screenshot

Comment: Ah have the "problem". I looked only at folders not at the files themselves (thought that folders are seen as files there). Thus functions for files. Question though is there also a way to add it to folders this way?

Comment: Add to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell ...` in the same fashion

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, is it possible to also add an icon to the "My Context Menu Name" Entry?

Comment: THank you very much Alex. One last point: I saw context menu items changing the font style, i.e. setting a bold text, is that also somehow possible?

Comment: You can't do that with this registry approach, only the default action for the file class will be bold.  It may be possible with a proper Shell Extension (although I doubt it) - I don't think your supposed to do it, else everyone would make their items bold.