# C# file passed to exe event

Tags: c#, file, csv, exe

I want to create a program that can open a CSV file. I want to be able to right click on the file name in windows and say open with my.exe.

What event in the .exe do I need to cover to handle the file being passed in?

Comment: This would be the arguments...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386469/c-sharp-adding-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-all-file-types

Answer (score 2):

This would be the arguments..

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args[0]);  // <-- args[0] contains filename
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

File name will be passed as a parameter in your `static void Main(string[] args)`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0}", args[0]); // Your file
}
```