# C# Programmatically "Open" on Context Menu a file

Tags: c#

How can I open a file with C#? 
This time, I would like to simulate below way in c#.

I want to achieve by c# code and try to avoid below situation.

```
Process.Start("sample.dot")
```

Then the result is

[image]

This should be sample.dot file.

Interestingly when I Open like below

[image]

The file name appeared I intended and it is saveable.

[image]

Only thing I could get the solution was seeking HKEY_CLASS_ROOT registory for entire file extensions. Then get the exe command and runs exactly same way.

But I am thinking there is more efficient solution.

[image]

Is it possible to simulat 'Open' by C# code?

It would be great if you can help me thanks!

Comment: Do you want to open a file with the default program in your application or do you want to let windows open your file extension with your application?

Comment: See This Will Help You Or Not
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386469/c-sharp-adding-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-all-file-types

Comment: @richej, Thank you for the comment. Default program is okay but not use Process.Start logic. 
basically when I use Process.Start with .dot file then it creates new instance for the word(makes different file name). I want to avoid this.

Comment: @SolankiSagar, Thank you for the comment! I want to achieve by c# :(

Comment: @TakeoNishioka You want to change the Open Behavior for Microsoft Word Document Templates? That open behavior is what the type **exists** for. You want to use Edit to modify it. | Also such a question would be very off topic for C#. So I am not sure I got you right.

Comment: @Christopher, Thank you for the comment. Not by the tool. The file open behaviour between 'Open with context menu' and Process.Start("sample.dot") is different in some reason. I would like to use 'Open' by C# code.

Comment: " 'Open with context menu' and Process.Start("sample.dot")" Because Open is not the Default Operation. When you doubleclick on a file, just punch it's name into the RunDialog or feed it to Process.Start(), the **Default** Action will be executed. The default action for .dot file is New. That is why it is bold in the Context Menu. Again, this different association/default operation is **literally** what the .dot format is there for. There is a 95% chance there is not even a bit of difference between a .dot and .doc file.

Comment: What you see back in Regedit are the verbs you can use for the  ProcessStartInfo.Verb property.  Like "New", "Open", "Edit", etc.  If you don't specify the verb then you get the default one, which is New.  So easy-peasy, set the Verb to "Open".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for helping me.

I finally solved by seeking the 'Open' menu command from the registory key.

Here is the code to seek.

shellComand takes : New, Open, Edit. Below code seek the Open menu context command.

```
static string SeekExtensionBehaviour(string path, string shellComand)
{            
    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);

    string command = "not found";

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extension)) return command;

    using (RegistryKey keyExt = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extension))
    {
        if (keyExt == null) return command;

        var keyRealExt = keyExt.GetValue("");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyRealExt.ToString())) return command;

        using (RegistryKey keyReal = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(keyRealExt.ToString()))
        {
            if (keyReal == null) return command;

            string keycommandPath = string.Format(@"shell\{0}\command", shellComand); // New, Open or Edit

            using (RegistryKey keyCommand = keyReal.OpenSubKey(keycommandPath))
            {
                command = keyCommand.GetValue("").ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    return command; // "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" /n "%1" /o "%u"
}

string command = SeekExtensionBehaviour("override shell command.dot", "Open");
```

Please replace the variable for 'command' paramters as it has %1 and %u. %1 is the path to oepn the file.

Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Open with MyThing]
"Icon"="C:\foo\myThing.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Open with MyThing\command]
@="C:\foo\myThing.exe \"%1\""

Answer (score 0):

What you see in that Context Menu, is a part of the File Association data in the Registery.

Back in the old days, the Interface was a bit clearer on this:

[image]

Source: https://techjourney.net/windows-file-types-open-edit-actions-associations-advanced-management-tools/

Those associations can be done with either a File Extension or a Protocoll (like http:). Sometimes even both seperately.

Most guides are about using Regedit for this:

- https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-78/how-do-i-create-default-association-files-no-extension
- https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-change-a-file-association-in-regedit

But .NET was class for this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.setvalue