# Add Custom Options when right-clicking a file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hello i want to show options like "Add to Queue" or "Add to Playlist >" when user right clicks an .mp3 file.

Reference Image:

[image: reference-image]

How can i do that with C# and winforms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# adding context menu item to windows explorer for all file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386469/c-sharp-adding-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-all-file-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is known as a "context menu".  And you can't do it directly in C#.  It's run from the Windows registry, which you can edit from C#, but you usually need to ask the user permission.

This should get you started:
[C# adding context menu item to windows explorer for all file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386469/c-sharp-adding-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-all-file-types)

Comment: When all your answer is a link to another stackoverflow post, it basically means you should post this as a comment, or vote to close as duplicate (if you believe it's really a duplicate). But you can post an enhanced answer based on the other post, keep a reference to the original answer, and post the improvements here.